# OpenGL: create a flickering black/white screen in accordance with the refresh rate (mobile)

Tags: android, colors, opengl-es, frames, flashing

I am trying to make an application where the screen should be flickering black and white. I have a 120hz android phone. I would like 2 frames black and then 1 frame white, 2 frames black and then 1 frame white etc. This would basically show 40 white flashes in one second, which is what I want to achieve.

How can I link my white/black drawings to the refresh rate?

Comment: Draw a white frame. Draw a black frame. Draw a black frame. Draw a white frame. Draw a black frame. Draw a black frame. Draw a white frame. Draw a black frame. Draw a black frame. etc...

Comment: What @user253751 said, plus you need to make sure that **vsync** is enabled. Knowing what bindings/framework you're using on mobile would help answering your question.